# post kubernetes installation support

Tags: installation

we are planning to install directly from kubernetes.io, instead getting it through vendor, for example open shift, rancher, etc.
How should we go about support if we have problem with our kubernetes cluster?
Of course, vendors also gets their kubernetes source code from kubernetes.io and don't change it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using OSS software directly means that whenever you face a problem you need to solve it yourself.
Having said that, there is a very wide array of communities filled with friendly people who would probably be happy to lend a hand, at least that's what I've learned through my experience.

A few places you should try are the [issues section](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues) of the kubernetes project, [kubernetes slack workspace](https://slack.k8s.io/), [r/kubernetes](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes).

Comment: There are Consulting companies who are willing to work on Kubernetes OSS. I have only spoke to one of them so not sure how solid my statement is. Kubernetes  knowledge seems to be fairly well spread and shared. It'll be great if OSS can some how have solid support also beside the great development.

Comment: You can hire a consultant for any job you can think of, the difference between that and managing your k8s cluster through a vendor is that the vendor is working with kubernetes constantly while consultants usually face a very wide array of issues in their work. I'm sure there are consulting companies that can offer k8s centric services but that cannot currently replace in house knowledge when managing your own cluster.